# Use visual composer for ACF WYSIWYG editor

Tags: wordpress, wysiwyg, advanced-custom-fields

For a client's website there is an ACF WYSIWYG editor field on the "edit category" backend that displays on the category page. For complicated reasons this is in addition to the category description field. They want to be able to do advanced layouts with this WYSIWYG using Visual Composer which is used elsewhere through out the site.

Short of having them create the layout on a post or page and then copying and pasting over the shortcode, which is more than they'd be able to handle, I can't find a way to add Visual Composer to this WYSIWYG. I'd settle for adding it to the category description as well.

Answer (score 1):

I used plugin, its not free but it seem to worked for me https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-acfvc-bridge-integrates-advanced-custom-fields-and-visual-composer-wordpress-plugins/19622052
it gives an option of Visual Composer in field type, having multiple VC fields being rendered on page slows the page in admin mode.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently using visual composer from the content area of a post/page to design a layout and copy the shortcode and paste them in my required ACF Field.